# What does the "done < $var" at the end of a loop do?

Tags: bash, shell

Just a simple question - I'm wondering what the following code is doing:

```
nlwd="$PWD/NLWD.txt"
cat /dev/null > $nlwd
echo "Enter filename to process:"
read name

while read line
do
uid="$(echo $line | cut -d, -f1)"
echo "$uid" | grep [0-9] >> $nlwd
done < $name
```

In particular, I'm wondering what the `done < $name` is doing.

Comment: It's not that the `done` is redirecting from the file, but that the `while` loop that the `done` terminates is taking input from the file. Since that while loop uses `read` to read from stdin, and you're directing stdin to the file for the duration of the loop... well, there you are.

Comment: By the way, you have a substantial number of bugs here related to insufficient quoting. Expansions need double quotes around them -- `"$name"`, `"$nlwd"`, etc -- to avoid string-splitting or glob expansion.

Comment: ...also, you need to pass grep `"[0-9]"` or `'[0-9]'`, not just `[0-9]`, or else if you have a file named with a single digit, the argument will be replaced with that filename (or, if there's more than one, those filenames) by the shell before `grep` is started.

Comment: Also, `uid="$(echo $line | cut -d, -f1)"` is needlessly inefficient. It would be much better written as `uid=${line%%,*}`, which will also have the effect of stripping everything after the first comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's taking a file name, reading that file line-by-line, and doing stuff with each line.

`<` is an input redirect, which means that the loop is taking its input from `$name`.

For example:

```
while read LINE
do
  echo $LINE
done < $name
```

...is essentially the same as:

```
cat $name
```

---

In response to your comment, the `cat /dev/null > $nlwd` just empties out the file's contents. This time, it uses the `>` output redirection to take the contents of `/dev/null` (which is Linux's black hole file), and outputs that emptiness into file represented by the `$nlwd` variable. Here's a simpler example:

```
$> echo "something" > something.txt
$> cat something.txt 
something
$> cat /dev/null > something.txt 
$> cat something.txt 
$>
```

---

Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null

Comment: This is good, thanks. I didn't ask this in my original question, but I'm wondering about `cat /dev/null > $nlwd` as well, if anyone can explain it.

Comment: Updated my response with some information relating to /dev/null.

Answer (score 1):

It's an input redirection. The `while` loop (and thus each command in the `while` loop, specifically `read`) will take its standard input from the file named by `$name`.